# Reducer for non-parallel for loops/multiline comprehensions

Tags: loops, julia, list-comprehension

Julia has a parallel macro for `for` loops, which allows things like:

```
s = @sync @parallel vcat for i in 1:9
  k = iseven(i) ? i÷2 : 3i+1
  k^2
end
```

and since the reducer specified is `vcat`, we get back an array of numbers.

Is it possible to do something like this with a normal for loop (without having to explicitly initialize and push! into the array)?

Since I'm only looking to reduce using vcat, another way to ask this question is: is there a neat readable multiline form of array comprehensions? It's possible to stretch to usual comprehension syntax like this:

```
 s = [
       (k = iseven(i) ? i÷2 : 3i+1;
       k^2)
       for i in 1:9
       ]
```

but that seems messy and less readable compared to the `@parallel vcat for` syntax. Is there a better way of doing multiline comprehensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending on @Gnimuc's answer, I think `mapreduce` plus [`do`-syntax](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/functions/#Do-Block-Syntax-for-Function-Arguments-1) is pretty nice:

```
julia> mapreduce(vcat, 1:9) do i
           k = iseven(i) ? i÷2 : 3i+1
           k^2
       end
9-element Array{Int64,1}:
  16
   1
 100
   4
 256
   9
 484
  16
 784
```

Comment: Thanks. Accepting this answer since this gives the neat and convenient syntax closest to the `@parallel vcat for` version.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is to write multiline functions(or do-blocks as @phg reminds) with a single line array comprehension or `map/mapreduce`:

```
s = [
       (k = iseven(i) ? i÷2 : 3i+1;
       k^2)
       for i in 1:9
       ]
```

This example is pure comprehension, no reducer is involved. Array comprehension is usually written in one line, for example, `s = [iseven(i) ? i÷2 : 3i+1 |> x->x^2 for i in 1:9]`. As @phg suggested, multi-line functions can be enclosed in a do-block:

```
julia> map(1:9) do x 
         k = iseven(x) ? x÷2 : 3x+1
         k^2
       end
```

However, no reducer such as `vcat` is needed in this case, but if the output of `f` in the above example is a vector:

```
julia> function f(x)
         k = iseven(x) ? x÷2 : 3x+1
         [k^2]
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> s = [f(i) for i in 1:9]
9-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [16] 
 [1]  
 [100]
 [4]  
 [256]
 [9]  
 [484]
 [16] 
 [784]
```

array comprehension will give you an array of vectors. This time you need to use `mapreduce` instead:

```
julia> mapreduce(f, vcat, 1:9)
9-element Array{Int64,1}:
  16
   1
 100
   4
 256
   9
 484
  16
 784
```